# Find a basis given...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$.
Given $$V:=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} u+v+w \\ au+bv+cw \\ a^2y+b^2v+c^2w \end{pmatrix} : u,v,w\in\mathbb{R} \right\}$$

and $V$ is said to be a subspace of $M_{3\times1}
(\mathbb{R})$.

So, should the basis of $V$ should be,
$W=u\begin{pmatrix}1\\a\\a^2\end{pmatrix}+v\begin{pmatrix}1\\b\\b^2\end{pmatrix}+w\begin{pmatrix}1\\c\\c^2\end{pmatrix}$

or am I wrong and if so what should the correct basis of $V$ be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that every element of $S$ can be written as $$x\begin{pmatrix}1\\a\\a^2\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}1\\b\\b^2\end{pmatrix}+z\begin{pmatrix}1\\c\\c^2\end{pmatrix}$$
for some $x,y,z \in \mathbb R$, the *set* $$B := \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}1\\a\\a^2\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1\\b\\b^2\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1\\c\\c^2\end{pmatrix} \right\}$$
is a spanning set (or a generator) for $S$. So, assuming that $a,b$ and $c$ make $B$ also a linearly independent set, then $B$ is basis for $S$.

Comment: How can $a$, $b$, and $c$ as scalars be linearly independent?  How can *they make $B$*? Certainly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix will be of help.